# Why Tikzplot overlapping graph for many data?

Tags: pgfplots, plot, tikz-datavisualization

When I am plotting the following data with tikzpicture give graph not good looking. The code is here:

```
  \begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X   P   $Q_B$   $Q_C$   $Q_D$   $Q_E$
1   A1  0.2500  0.2500  0.5000  0.5000
2   A2  0.1667  0.1250  0.5000  0.5000
3   A3  0.1250  0.1250  0.1250  0.1250
4   A4  0.0833  0.0156  0.1250  0.2500
5   A5  0.0417  0.0005  0.0625  0.1667
6   A6  0.0250  0.0000  0.0313  0.1250
7   A7  0.0250  0.0002  0.0156  0.1250
8   A8  0.0125  0.0000  0.0010  0.0625
9   A9  0.1250  0.0625  0.2500  0.2500
11  A10 0.0833  0.0156  0.2500  0.2500
12  A11 0.0625  0.0039  0.2500  0.2500
13  A12 0.0417  0.0020  0.0625  0.2500
14  A13 0.0208  0.0000  0.0313  0.0833
15  A14 0.0625  0.0156  0.1250  0.1250
16  A15 0.0208  0.0002  0.0313  0.0625
17  A16 0.0078  0.0000  0.0039  0.0313
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.7,yscale=0.3]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Q Series,
    ylabel=P Values,
    %width=10cm,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  xmajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
    xtick=data,
    xtick = {1,...,20},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,...,0.6},
    xticklabels from table={data.dat}{P},
  ]
        \addplot [blue,thick,mark=square*] table [
        x=X,
%            % this worked so far, ...
 %            y=$Q_B$,
                % ... but now we have to use this and it works
        y expr=\thisrow{$Q_B$},
        ]{data.dat};
            \addlegendentry{$Q_B$ series}
        \addplot [red,thick,mark=square*] table [
           x=X,
           y expr=\thisrow{$Q_C$},
        ]{data.dat};
           \addlegendentry{$Q_C$ series}
        \addplot [black,dashed,thick,mark=square*] table [
           x=X,
        y expr=\thisrow{$Q_D$},
        ]{data.dat};
          \addlegendentry{$Q_D$ series}
         \addplot [black,dashed,thick,mark=square*] table [
     x=X,
   y expr=\thisrow{$Q_E$},
   ]{data.dat};
   \addlegendentry{$Q_E$ series}
     \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

this produces the graph :
[image]

But I need the following clear good looking graph:

[image]

The second graph is generated by Libreoffice. How can I produce by Latex?

Comment: Remove `[xscale=0.7,yscale=0.3]` and provide a proper `width` and `height` to the `axis` environment ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow I have done this but still the graph is not looking so good. $A1,A2,...., A16$ are over lapping. How can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest either increasing `width` or to use a smaller font size in general or for the `xticklabels` by providing something like `xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize}`.

Comment: You need also `mark options={solid}` for dashed lines

Answer (score 1):

[image]

changes in comparison to your MWE are marked with `% <--`. Main changes: (i) scaled marks, (ii) reduced font size to `\tiny`, (iii) determined width of graph, (iV) removed scaling of picture.

```
  \begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X   P   $Q_B$   $Q_C$   $Q_D$   $Q_E$
1   A1  0.2500  0.2500  0.5000  0.5000
2   A2  0.1667  0.1250  0.5000  0.5000
3   A3  0.1250  0.1250  0.1250  0.1250
4   A4  0.0833  0.0156  0.1250  0.2500
5   A5  0.0417  0.0005  0.0625  0.1667
6   A6  0.0250  0.0000  0.0313  0.1250
7   A7  0.0250  0.0002  0.0156  0.1250
8   A8  0.0125  0.0000  0.0010  0.0625
9   A9  0.1250  0.0625  0.2500  0.2500
10  A10 0.0833  0.0156  0.2500  0.2500
11  A11 0.0625  0.0039  0.2500  0.2500
12  A12 0.0417  0.0020  0.0625  0.2500
13  A13 0.0208  0.0000  0.0313  0.0833
14  A14 0.0625  0.0156  0.1250  0.1250
15  A15 0.0208  0.0002  0.0313  0.0625
16  A16 0.0078  0.0000  0.0039  0.0313
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}%[xscale=0.7,yscale=0.3] <-- deleted
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth, % <-- added
    xlabel=Q Series,
    ylabel=P Values,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  xmajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
    xtick=data,
    xmin=1, xmax=16,    % <-- added
    xtick = {1,...,16},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,...,0.6},
    xticklabels from table={data.dat}{P},
    font=\tiny,% <-- added
    mark options={solid, draw, scale=0.4},% <-- added
                ]
\addplot[blue,mark=square*] table [x=X, y expr=\thisrow{$Q_B$},
        ] {data.dat};
\addplot [red,mark=square*] table [x=X, y expr=\thisrow{$Q_C$},
        ] {data.dat};
\addplot[black,dashed,mark=square*] table [x=X,y expr=\thisrow{$Q_D$},
        ] {data.dat};
\addplot[black,dashed,mark=square*] table [x=X,y expr=\thisrow{$Q_E$},
        ] {data.dat};
\legend{$Q_B$ series, $Q_C$ series, $Q_D$ series, $Q_E$ series}
     \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```